# Powershell : How to create IIS 6 Virtual Directory/Web application under a Subfolder

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I am trying to create a Web application/VirtualDirectory under a specific subfolder of a IIS 6 website using Powershell as show below:

#### IIS WebSite Structure   <<<>>> Physical Directory Structure

```
Test (website) ---------------->   c:\InetPub
    SubDirectory ------------------>   ..\Subdirectory
       gadgets (Web App) -----------------> ..\Gadgets
```

---

#### Script

```
$WebSiteName = “Test”
$virtualDirName = “subdirectory\gadgets”
$appPoolName = “DefaultAppPool”
$VirtalDirHomePath = "c:\InetPub\Subdirectory\Gadgets"

$iisWebSite = Get-WmiObject "IISWebServerSetting" `
                 -Namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2"     `
                 -filter "ServerComment like '%$WebSiteName%'"
$virtualDirSettings = [wmiclass] "root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDirSetting"
$newVDir = $virtualDirSettings.CreateInstance()
$newVDir.Name = ($iisWebSite.Name + '/ROOT/' + $virtualDirName)
$newVDir.Path = $VirtalDirHomePath
$newVDir.Put();

$nvdir = $iisWebSite.Name + '/ROOT/' + $virtualDirName

$nvdir = $nvdir.Replace("\", "/") 

$v = Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebVirtualDir -Namespace root\microsoftiisv2 `
                       -filter "Name='$nvdir'"

#Create WebAppliction
$v.AppCreate3(2, $appPoolName, 1)
```

If I specify the `$virtualDirName` with forward slash path separator (`subdirectory/gadgets`) , `$newVDir.Put()` call throws following exception

> Exception calling "Put" with "0"
>   argument(s): "Win32: The system cannot
>   find the path specified.

If I change the `$virtualDirName` with backslash path separator (subdirectory\gadgets) `$newVDir.Put()` call returns successfully.

I am not sure whether this is the right way.

Is there any better way to create Web Application/VirtualDirectory under a specific subfolder and How can I list VirtualDirectory/WebApplication created under a subfolder.

Comment: Does the variable $VirtalDirHomePath need to be set to anything?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. Added missing $VirtalDirHomePath value

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution to [create a virtual directory in IIS 6.0 through scripting](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/82373078-e14f-4f20-9a1f-883c2e94dc8d.mspx?mfr=true), which *doesn't* involve PowerShell, is to use the **iisvdir.vbs** script:

```
SET webSiteName=Test
SET virtualDirName=subdirectory/gadgets
SET virtualDirHomePath=C:\InetPub\Subdirectory\Gadgets

cscript %SystemRoot%\system32\iisvdir.vbs /create %webSiteName% %virtualDirName% %virtualDirHomePath%
```

Note that the virtual directory path in `virtualDirName` is specified using **forward slashes**.

You can also [list the virtual directories in a specific path](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/15c4674f-bf0e-4ce6-9d32-c5a1f69c8741.mspx?mfr=true) using the same **iisvdir.vbs** script:

```
cscript %SystemRoot%\system32\iisvdir.vbs /query %webSiteName%/%virtualDirName%
```

Comment: PowerShell can do it as well with ADSI. The OP was using WMI, I was able to reproduce the same issue, but ADSI was able to get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try. It connects to the root of website 1 (Default Website). Creates a IIsWebDirectory object for the gadgets folder and assigns it an application pool.

```
$root = [adsi] "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT"
$vDir = $root.Create("IIsWebDirectory", "SubDirectory\Gadgets")
$vDir.AppCreate3(2, "DefaultAppPool", $false)
$vDir.AppFriendlyName = "Andy Test"
$vDir.SetInfo()
```

If you need to connect to a website other than the default web site you can get the ID of the website with this command:

```
([adsi] "IIS://localhost/W3SVC").psbase.Children | ? {$_.psbase.schemaclassname -eq "IIsWebServer" } | select Path, ServerComment
```

Output:

```
Path                         ServerComment
----                         -------------
IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1      {Default Web Site}
IIS://localhost/W3SVC/2      {WHS site}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, as it turns out my problem was that "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT" was actually something like "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/234564541/ROOT"

Comment: @KevHunter Yea, the default website is usually 1 unless it's deleted/recreated. All other websites have a randomly generated ID.

Comment: @KevHunter I updated my answer to show you how you can get the ID's of the other IIS websites.